# `experiments.topLevelAwait: true` does unexpectedly not work - ReactJS still throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, async-await

I have the following `index.js` file,

```js
import { DataStore } from "aws-amplify";
import { Todo } from "./models";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

await new DataStore.save(
  new Todo({
    name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  })
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Because of the `await` code snippet, I receive the following error when I run `npm run start`,

```
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
    at /home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyDetectionParserPlugin.js:54:11
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:16)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
    at JavascriptParser.walkAwaitExpression (/home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2320:29)
    at JavascriptParser.walkExpression (/home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2250:10)
    at JavascriptParser.walkExpressionStatement (/home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1638:8)
    at JavascriptParser.walkStatement (/home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1565:10)
    at JavascriptParser.walkStatements (/home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1459:9)
    at JavascriptParser.parse (/home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:3353:9)
    at /home/saif/Projects/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1087:26
```

It seems easy enough to understand, so I create a `webpack.config.js` file in the root directory as the same level as the `project.json`, and fill the contents of it with it,

```js
module.exports = {
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
  },
};
```

I still get the error. Am I supposed to put this somewhere else?

For context, these are my versions,

```
❯ node --version
v17.9.0
❯ npm --version 
8.5.5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I know Currently there is no top level await support in react , try with this way.

```
(async () => {
    await new DataStore.save(
      new Todo({
        name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      })
    )
})()
```

Comment: This gives me `Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (14:2) eslint` instead.

Comment: [Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lucid-newton-o8wrbt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) it works for me , also in app created by **create-react-app**